# What is an example of a power automorphism of a group that isn't a universal power automorphism?

Tags: finite-groups, automorphism-group, power-automorphism

A power automorphism maps every subgroup of a group to within itself, with equality if the group is finite. More specifically, for a subgroup $H$ of $G$, a power automorphism $f$ has $f(H) \subseteq H$. If $G$ is finite then $f(H) = H$.

There are lots of these of the form $f:G \to G$, $f(x) = x^n$, especially for finite abelian groups. This is a universal power automorphism.

I want to find an example of a non-trivial power automorphism of a finite group that isn't universal, particularly with some insight in how it is constructed. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: So a power automorphism of a finite group is just any old automorphism? You haven't really given a definition for the non-universal case.

Comment: @SteveD: A power automorphism is not just any old automorphism, it's one that maps any subgroup to itself. The OP's explanation isn't very clear but the [wikipedia discussion of a power automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_automorphism) is. The OP doesn't need to give the definitions because they are well known (but not, apparently, by you).

Comment: It is called a power automorphism because any element $g \in G$ of order $n$ must be mapped to a power of $g$, as $\{1, g, g^2, \dots, g^{n-1}\}$ is a cyclic group, and is preserved by the power automorphism. The thing is, the powers may vary for each $g$. I think it is kind of strange definition. I think a power automorphism should be what is called a universal power automorphism.

Comment: I added some clarification of what precisely a power automorphism is.

Comment: Small typo: you mean it maps every subgroup to itself, not every subset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example: consider the automorphism of the quaternion group $Q_8$ whose action on its generators $i$, $j$, $k$ is as follows: $$i \mapsto i \hspace{10pt} j \mapsto -j \hspace{10pt} k \mapsto -k$$

(Of course, this also works for $i \mapsto -i , j \mapsto j , k \mapsto -k$ and $i \mapsto -i \hspace{10pt} j \mapsto -j \hspace{10pt} k \mapsto k$.)

Comment: At the risk of embodying all that is wrong with this site, let me mention that this example is mentioned in the paper [Cooper, Christopher D. H. Power automorphisms of a group. Math. Z. 107 1968 335–356] (which can be seen [here](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?PPN266833020_0107)) In fact, all inner automorphisms of $Q_8$ are also examples.

Comment: No problem here-- that's a good reference!

Comment: I will need to verify this before I accept your answer. Thanks!