# Are all power automorphisms of a finite abelian group of the form $f(x)=x^n$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group, power-automorphism

An example of a universal power automorphism, that is automorphisms of the form $f(x)=x^n$, is easy to find in an abelian group. Any power $n$ will work as long it is relatively prime to the orders of all elements of the group.

More generally, a power automorphisms sends any $g \in G$ to a power of $g$. Equivalently, it maps all subgroups $H$ of $G$ to H. My hunch is that any power automorphism of an abelian group must be a universal power automorphism. Is this true?

(In general, power automorphisms that aren't universal power automorphisms do exist for finite groups. See [my question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679968/what-is-an-example-of-a-power-automorphism-of-a-group-that-isnt-a-universal-pow). The example in that case is non-abelian, however.)

Comment: I think the decomposition of an abelian group into the product of cyclic groups would be very helpful in answering this question. It is where I get my hunch.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1132336/688539

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every finitely generated abelian group has a decomposition

$$ \mathbb{Z}/n_1\oplus\mathbb{Z}/n_2\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}/n_k $$

for some moduli $n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_k$.

Let $\phi$ be a so-called power automorphism. Use $g_i$ for the coordinate basis, so $g_1=(1,0,\cdots,0)$ for example. Then $\phi(g_i)=e_ig_i$ for $i=1,\cdots,k$ for some numbers $e_1,\cdots,e_k$. (In multiplicative notation, these would be exponents.) So $\phi$ acts "diagonally" via the formula

$$ \phi(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=(e_1x_1,e_2x_2,\cdots,e_nx_n). $$

Since $\phi$ is a power automorphism, we may write

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \phi(1,1,\cdots,1) & =e(1,1,\cdots,1) \\ & =(e,e,\cdots,e) \end{array} $$

for some integer $e$ and also we may write

$$ \phi(1,1,\cdots,1)=(e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_k). $$

Therefore, $e\equiv e_i \mod n_i$ for each $i=1,\cdots,k$ and so we have

$$ \phi(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=(e_1x_1,\cdots,e_kx_k)=(ex_1,\cdots,ex_k) $$

i.e. $\phi(x)=ex$ (or in multiplicative notation, $\phi(x)=x^{\large e}$), Q.E.D.

Note it's okay for any of $n_1,\cdots,n_k$ to be $0$, so $G$ doesn't need to be finite.

---

It's not true for infinite torsion abelian groups. In particular, we can get "power-like" automorphisms that are not actually integer power maps. For instance, in the $p$-primary component of the additive factor group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, the so-called Prufer $p$-group which is the additive group of $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ mod the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}$, we can multiply by a $p$-adic integer which doesn't need to be a rational integer, or even rational at all.

Comment: This is the sort of approach I was thinking of. However, can you elaborate on your jump from the systems of modular equations to $\phi(x)=x^e$. I am having trouble explicitly seeing the logic.

Comment: I think you need to establish that $e_i=e_j$ if $|G_i|=|G_j|$, which I don't think is hard to do. Then you use the Chinese remainder theorem. If you work this out I will happily accept your answer.

Comment: @abnry CRT isn't necessary. I spelled it out more.

Comment: Great, much clearer for me. Thanks!