# Does there exist a finite group whose automorphism group is simple?

Tags: finite-groups, automorphism-group

Ignore any trivial cases. Also, even if some examples exist for $|G|$ small, I still want to know if there are simple automorphism groups for arbitrarily large $|G|$.

For such a group to exist, something catastrophically wrong must happen, as there are definitionally many, many normal subgroups of the automorphism group. See [here for some examples](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Automorphism_group_of_a_group#Subgroups).

The inner automorphisms are the most famous. Universal power automorphisms are another. I've asked some [recent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691090/are-all-power-automorphisms-of-a-finite-abelian-group-of-the-form-fx-xn) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691090/are-all-power-automorphisms-of-a-finite-abelian-group-of-the-form-fx-xn) about those.

So my question, what groups have a simple automorphism group? And less preciously, what is going on when/if this happens?

Comment: Turns out, MO [also has](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36218/criteria-for-autg-to-be-simple) a question about this, with quite a nice answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $G/Z(G)$ is the inner automorphism group, and it is normal in $Aut(G)$, this has to be either trivial or all of $Aut(G)$.  Thus $G$ is either abelian or a simple complete group.  In the abelian case, you've already found a nice set of examples: $Z_2^n$ for $n\ge3$.  For the simple complete groups, the Mathieu group $M_{23}$ works.

Answer (score 4):

I can now answer half of my question. If $G = Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2$, then $Aut(G) = GL_3(Z_2) = PSL(3,2)$, which is simple [according to this page](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Projective_special_linear_group:PSL(3,2)). I have no insight as to why it is simple. I also have no insight if this is just a freak example, as $|G|=8$ is small in this case. So I would really love a better answer.

Comment: This should happen for all of the PSL(n, 2) groups (for n > 2), shouldn’t it? Normally you only have easy access to the (non-simple) GL(n, q) as an automorphism group, but it sort of “just so happens” to also be PSL(n, q) in the q = 2 case, since there’s only one nonzero scalar. Aside from that, I don’t know anything about the problem.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if there is something unique about $GL(n,Z_2)$, due to $Z(G)=G$, if I understand it right.